# How to fix CS0029

Tags: visual-studio

hi im making a c# project in visyal studio 2019 and i got the error  CS0029 in this code:

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

```
    this.button2.Enabled = false;

    progressBar1 = 100;

        this.button2.Enabled = true;
```

Any help? im using the progress bar plugin just so you know

Comment: What is progressBar1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CS0029 is *Cannot implicitly convert type 'type' to 'type'*.

In this case, `progressBar1` is (assumedly) an instance of `ProgressBar`, yet you're trying to assing the value 100 to it, which has type `int`. These types differ, which is not allowed.

You probaly want:

```cs
progressBar1.Value = 100;
```